# Android Proguard issues with Lamdas in library module

Tags: android, proguard

I have an android project and it depends on a library module. I have an interface in my module like this:

```
   public interface SimpleAnimationListener extends Animation.AnimationListener {
    @Override
    default void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        onAnimation(Type.START);
    }

    @Override
    default void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        onAnimation(Type.END);
    }

    @Override
    default void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        onAnimation(Type.REPEAT);
    }

    void onAnimation(Type type);

    enum Type {
        START,
        END,
        REPEAT
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void fadeViewOut(@NonNull View view, int duration) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    anim.setDuration(duration);
    anim.setAnimationListener((SimpleAnimationListener) type -> {
        if (type == SimpleAnimationListener.Type.END) {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Whenever I use this interface in my app project. I get following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
        at Zt.onAnimationStart(lambda)
```

In my mappings.txt I have this:

```
com.example.mymodule.interfaces.SimpleAnimationListener -> Wt:
<...>
com.example.mymodule.utils.-$$Lambda$AnimationUtils$rrH5aPAPZuoC__1-9DiD10TFdgY -> Zt:
        android.view.View f$0 -> a
```

Tried adding following to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep public class com.example.mymodule.utils.AnimationUtils
-keep public interface com.example.mymodule.interfaces.SimpleAnimationListener
```

Then in my mappings I would get:

```
com.example.mymodule.interfaces.SimpleAnimationListener -> com.example.mymodule.interfaces.SimpleAnimationListener:
<...>
com.example.mymodule.utils.-$$Lambda$AnimationUtils$rrH5aPAPZuoC__1-9DiD10TFdgY -> Yt:
    android.view.View f$0 -> a
```

This would also fail. But error would point to **Yt**. If I stop using my interface which overrides some methods, then app is working, but since original interfaces have multiple methods, I can't use lamdas with them. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: did you get solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you keep enum as well?
Cause we dont want to strip enum right.

If not try the following

`-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
-keep public class com.example.mymodule.utils.AnimationUtils { *; }
-keep public interface com.example.mymodule.interfaces.SimpleAnimationListener { *; }`